# Matplotlib axis labels

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I reduce the number of ticks on the axes with matplotlib (without using pyplot)?

```
    self.figure = Figure((2.0, 2.0))
    self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
    self.canvas.setParent(self)
    self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
    self.figure.subplots_adjust(left=0.18)
    self.axes.fill(x, y, 'b')
```

now....?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pyplot it was `xticks(...)`, but I couldn't find that in matplotlib.

It turns out, you have to use `set_xticks`